# xcode multiple main methods

Tags: c, xcode, process, program-entry-point

I am using Xcode for c programming. I have a project called system_commands. Inside this project I have a file A, and a file B.

This is file A:

```
int main(int argc, char *argvector[])
{
    char *arguments[] = {"./runProcesses","Hello","World",NULL};
    execvp("./runProcesses", arguments);
    return 0;
}
```

File A simply "executes" File B, and file B is here:

```
int main(int argc, char *argvector[])
{

    for(int i = 0; i < argc; i++)
    {
        printf("%s", argvector[i]);
    }
//some forks etc
}
```

Obviously, Xcode will not allow this, since there are two main methods inside the project. But is there a workaround somehow? Do I really have to create another project, so that the files reside in different projects?
Or is there a way I can execvp() a file without main method?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you don't want two projects, you can create a second target ("File" - "New" - "Target..." and choose another "Console app") for your second program. Put your other `main.c` there:

[image: two targets]
 You can also go to the Target settings for the first console app and add a dependency for the second console app, that way, it will build the second, if needed, whenever you run the first one.

[image: dependency]

Frankly, this multiple target approach is designed when you have an app with some shared code base, but it can be used in this scenario, too.

---

The other approach is to go ahead and have multiple projects, but work with them under a single "workspace". So, create a folder, create your two projects in that folder, and then create a "Workspace" (which I called "MyProject", in my example below) and add the two `xcodeproj` files for the two separate projects ("FirstApp" and "SecondApp" in my example below).

So, in Xcode it looks like:

[image: workspace]

And in the file system, it looks like:

[image: filesystem]

So, in this case, you have two projects, but you can work with them together under a single workspace, making it really easy to work with both projects at the same time. Just open that `xcworkspace` workspace rather than the individual `xcodeproj` files.

Comment: What a great answer. Thank you so much.